# Unexpected error in driver invocation: invalid driver name: SWIFT_EXEC-no-coverage

Tags: swift, xcode, code-coverage

When using [this](https://gist.github.com/grigorye/f6dfaa9f7bd9dbb192fe25a6cdb419d4) script on Xcode 13.2.1, the Swift compiler returns the error:

```
SwiftDriver Alamofire normal i386 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler (in target 'Alamofire' from project 'Pods')
...
error: Unexpected error in driver invocation: invalid driver name: SWIFT_EXEC-no-coverage
```

Probably because there is a conflict with the script `SWIFT_EXEC-no-coverage`, is there anything that can be done to sort this issue?

For the moment I had to disable this script by commenting this line out to be able to compile the project:

```
#      config.build_settings['SWIFT_EXEC'] = '$(SRCROOT)/../Scripts/SWIFT_EXEC-no-coverage'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we [figured](https://gist.github.com/grigorye/f6dfaa9f7bd9dbb192fe25a6cdb419d4#gistcomment-4023221) it out offline, now only "swiftc" is the [allowed](http://github.com/apple/swift-driver/blob/16111276386b8bad5e713e72d0f1c08130558171/Sources/SwiftDriver/Driver/Driver.swift#L1105) name for the swift driver - hence try renaming "SWIFT_EXEC-no-coverage" to "swiftc" (and adjust the value in Podfile).